# Jquery UI Dialog with embedded form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have "User-settings" page in my ASP.Net MVC3 application. This page contains a lot of fancy Javascript and CSS for animations. This page allows the users to change their website settings and does this through a post on itself.

I have now been tasked with displaying this page in a Jquery UI dialog box. I have been able to successfully accomplish this with the following Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#settings-link').click(function () {
            var tag = $("<div></div>");
            $.ajax({
                url: "MyWebsite/MySettings",
                success: function (data) {
                    tag.html(data).dialog({ modal: true }).dialog('open');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The trouble I am having is as follows

When a user makes a change to their settings and clicks the "submit" button, the jquery dialog box disappears and the postback page is displayed in the background page. Ideally, I would like to allow users to make changes and postback to be displayed in the jquery dialog itself. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Where is your form? Is it inside your dialog markup?

Comment: @jrummell - my form is embedded deep inside the html code of "MyWebsite/Mysettings" url. I am currently displaying the entire web page in the jquery dialog

Comment: Where's the 'submit' function for this? The idea is **exactly** the same as what you're already displaying. What are you having difficulties with?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your html, but keep in mind that the dialog plugin will move your div to the end of the body of the page, so that may have adverse affects on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must you form inside dialog post data using AJAX? Do you use unobtrusive AJAX? Also please check if jQuery UI dialog creates `iframe` (use developers tools (F12) for this).

**EDIT:**

To display post result inside dialog you may use following way:

1. Declare your form as AJAX form: use @Ajax.BeginForm() and add link to jquery.ajax-unobtrusive.js to your page if it is not done yet.
2. Inside javascript that displays dialog give an Id to div contains wrapper div 
   `var tag = $("<div id='form-wrapper-div'></div>");`
3. In AJAX options set UpdateTargetId to "form-wrapper-div"

Now POST results will be displayed inside dialog.

Comment: @STO- no, the jquery UI dialog is not creating an iframe. How can I display my page in an iframe? I believe that might solve my problem

Comment: Thanks. I first tried iframe and it worked but I did not like the result since the iframe is within the modal dialog and the dual scroll bars and margins are distracting. I instead opted to use unobtrusive AJAX and it works great now! The modal dialog is no longer closed since form post through unobtrusive AJAX does not reload the page